# python deleting information from a file and writing new information

Tags: python-3.x

Ok, I have tried researching this topic but it is confusing and I am not for sure if that is what I want or not. Anyways, I was watching a you tube tutorial on a python pygame game. I got through the videos and he did not show how to make like a high scoring thing instead of just the score for that specific game in time. So I am trying to grasp the concept before going into the gaming code and doing it for real. So I want to be able to create the file and I would run that one time and then I would delete the write code and leave the reading code. So I created the file and here is the code I have right now.

```
def highscore():
    question=int(input("What is 5+5=?:"))
    if question==10:
        highread=open('high.txt', 'r')
        text=highread.read()
        if text==1:
            highread.close()
            high=open('high.txt', 'w')
            high.write('2\n')
            high.close()
            highread=open('high.txt', 'r')
            text=highread.read()
            print("Your new score of", text)
            highread.close()
        highread.close()
    else:
        print("Wrong!")
highscore()
```

I am pretty sure the file has "1" in it right now. So I want it to make a "2" now to represent someone beating the high score and thus the file needs to update because of that. It is not printing the new results, so I know something is wrong. What is wrong? There is no error message but it isn't doing what I want it to, which is to just print the number 2. I am using python 3.4.3 by the way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's reading in the file as a string. So you would need to check for `"1"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your if condition. Here `text` is string variable. If you are to see if a string contains a particular substring/character or not you should use `find()` which returns index of substring/character in string if found or a negative value if not found.
Try this:

```
def highscore():
question=int(input("What is 5+5=?:"))
if question==10:
    highread=open('high.txt', 'r')
    text=highread.read()
    if len(text)>0:
        highread.close()
        high=open('high.txt', 'w')
        high.write('2')
        high.close()
        highread=open('high.txt', 'r')
        text=highread.read()
        print("Your new score of", text)
        highread.close()
    highread.close()
else:
    print("Wrong!")
```

Feel free to ask for any further clarifications.

Comment: Ok, I have a couple of questions here. 1. "if text.find("1")>=0:" is confusing because that 1 is going to change as people are going to beat the high score over and over again. So how is that going to work? 2. "high.write('2\n')" wont this write to the second line and not like write over the first line in the document? I just need one number to be in the document and when someone beats the score, the number gets deleted and their score gets put there instead. I am a little confused here. Is there like maybe a delete thing instead or what?

Comment: For 1: You could use a list for scores and get values like 1 or 2 from the list. For 2: If you just need one number to be stored then why bother create a separate file for it. You could simple use a variable. What 'w' mode does is deletes the opens a new file for writing if the file does not exist and if the file exists it simple overwrites the file with new text.

Comment: Ok so the second question looks like it would be better sense it writes over it anyways. However, when I get rid of the /n so it does not make a second line, it does not print. What to do? I just want it to read, if the player score is more than the file number, then write over that and the print. That is in theory of what I want to do. That question I ask in the start  of like what is 5+5 is just to like simulate a game sort of speak.  How to do that maybe?

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Thanks.